# Generate automatically a linearLayout with TextView ( with Design)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I have some problem I need to generate dynamically several linearLayout with at least 4 TextView.
when i try to open it my application crash here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Integer.valueOf(nb_com); i++) {
    String[] laCom = tab_les_commandes[i].split(":");
    final String id= laCom[0];
    String[] tabDate = laCom[1].split("-");
    String laDate = tabDate[2] + "/" + tabDate[1] + "/" + tabDate[0];

    LinearLayout layoutVertical = new LinearLayout(this);
    layoutVertical.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layoutVertical.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    LinearLayout layoutHorizontal = new LinearLayout(this);
    layoutHorizontal.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layoutHorizontal.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView titleView = new TextView(this);
    titleView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    titleView.setTextColor(vertLogo);
    titleView.setText("N° Commande ");
    titleView.setShadowLayer(5,5,5,R.color.black);



    TextView titleView2 = new TextView(this);
    titleView2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    titleView2.setTextColor(R.color.white);
    titleView2.setText(laCom[0]);
    titleView2.setShadowLayer(5,5,5,R.color.black);

    layoutHorizontal.addView(titleView);
    layoutHorizontal.addView(titleView2);
```

i create 6 another titleView every 4 title i put a
layoutHorizontal.removeAllViews();

and at last i make a setContentView(layoutVertical);.

if someone can help me .

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the scope of the `layoutVertical` object inside your `for` block with the line `LinearLayout layoutVertical = new LinearLayout(this);`

Thus this variable is not available to outside the `for` block where you are trying to `setContentView(layoutVertical);.`

Thus you are trying to setContentView on `null`

Solution is to move the variable definition `LinearLayout layoutVertical` to outside the `for` block

Comment: Hi thanks for trying to help me so I tried to do it again in a different way because unfortunately it doesn't work I put my code back on post if you can help me once more please.